# What is the "--servername" in "vim --servername VIM test.R"?

Tags: linux, r, vim, vim-plugin, vim-r

I just installed the `vim-r-plugin` on a Linux server and I found this issue (see below figure) prompted from the R console window (vimcom: Did you pass the --servername argument to Vim? ...) when I typed `"\rf"`:
[image]

To solve the issue I followed the instructions [here](http://www.lepem.ufc.br/jaa/r-plugin.html#r-plugin-bash-setup) and was trying to find the "servername" and tested some commands such like:
[image]

But I have no idea what's the "--servername" I should use here. Any suggestions or answers? Thanks!

Comment: On that help page, every instance of `servername` says to use it with the argument `VIM`. Did you install vim with the `servername` capability enabled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`--servername` is usually followed by some arbitrarily chosen name. This allows external processes like those used by your R plugin to interact with a running instance of Vim.

When the feature is available, GVim always starts as if you added `--servername GVIMn` where `n` is a number incremented for each new GUI window. You can see it on the right of the window title.

But you are using Vim so you'll need to do that explicitely:

```
$ vim --servername FOO
```